# registration form for wordpress, buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, buddypress, bbpress

i wanna create a social Network on wordpress , bbpress buddypress,
i have plan for registration system but i don't know how do it in my website, this website for some reason must have strong security , so please help me find how do this or introduce me some usefull wordpress plugin. my plan is :
step 1 : People come to the website!
step 2 : they should register to access the website(buddypress&..)
my problem :
step 3 : there's a registration form , they should fill it , one of them is something that they should select(like question is how old are you and they should choose their age )
step4: its next stage of registration ,scheduled question , there's 3 question (questions are random, questions select from the answer of how old are you step3, for ex questions for people who select 18 ... 30 is different from who select 50..60) it has a timer and after 2 times of wrong answer or timeout ip will block , but if the answer is correct then members rate for their account(like paid membership pro plugin)

in other word i wanna a registration system that people choose something and from that choose they should answer some questions in specify time if they wrong they will block and cant access to website again but if answer correct then according to the first question divide into different level of membership with specify access 
please tell me your suggestions and helps to create it and secure it or if there's a plugin please introduce me

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free plugin - http://ultimatemember.com/

Read more about the features, before you implement the same in your site. 
https://ultimatemember.com/features

If you want to see it in live action, can head on to my site, where I have implemented the same to get the functionalities listed in your question. 
http://gstindia.net/